# How should a tag for changes in Latin language through time be named?

Tags: discussion, tags

For now, I named it [language-change](https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/language-change). [language-history](https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/language-history) feels better. But I'm almost sure there's established term for this, which I don't know. Should I change the tag name? It's early enough to do this easily.

Comment: I see language history as a bigger concept that includes language change. It also includes etymology, for example. I believe both tags could have their uses.

Comment: @JoonasIlmavirta Etymology tracks the evolution of a single word, right? I could see value in also having a tag that refers to broader "trend changes" in the language, such as changes in declension/conjugation forms. HDE's proposed 'language-evolution' tag appeals.

Comment: @Brian, I find the language-evolution badge appealing as well, but it could also be useful to have some more specific badges in addition to a wider badge covering all change. It takes a while to see what kinds of badges would be actually useful, so I don't have a strong opinion yet.

Comment: @JoonasIlmavirta <nod>, I'm definitely favor of a "reserve judgment and refactor tags as the site grows" approach here.

Comment: Could we have you accept the most upvoted answer? At this point, it seems pretty well decided.

Comment: @QPaysTaxes: accepted. The other one can become a synonym later.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[Evolutionary linguistics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evolutionary_linguistics) is a discipline that should cover this, so I suggest we use [language-evolution](https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/language-evolution).

Comment: I believe that evolutionary linguistics deals more with how languages come to be than with how they change over time.

Answer (score 3):

The term linguists use, which may be the official one you're looking for, is "diachronic change." That may be a little jargony for non-linguist users, though. (It occurs as part of the field of study known as "diachronic linguistics" or "historical linguistics." But I think those would be worse, as well as not in fact accurate.)