# Should we tag geographical/contextual variations in Latin language, and if so, how?

Tags: discussion, tags

We already have the following meta questions for establishing tag scope:

- [Latin language eras](https://latin.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/14/latin-language-eras)
- [How should a tag for changes in Latin language through time be named?](https://latin.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10/how-should-a-tag-for-changes-in-latin-language-through-time-be-named)

The former is a static classification, while the latter focuses on the changes that occurred over time.

Should we also institute tags for context- or geographic-specific variations of Latin?  The particular example that comes to mind is [ecclesiastical-latin](https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ecclesiastical-latin), which I think should be kept since it's such a major division of the language.  In a comment, Nathaniel also proposes [vulgar-latin](https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/vulgar-latin).

For geographical variations, per the [Wikipedia article on Latin spelling and pronunciation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Latin_spelling_and_pronunciation#Ecclesiastical_pronunciation) (italic formatting in original, bold added):

> Because of the central position of Rome within the Catholic Church, an Italian pronunciation of Latin became commonly accepted, but studies by Frederick Brittain (published as *Latin in Church; the history of its pronunciation*) show that this was not the case until the latter part of the 19th century. This pronunciation corresponds to that of the Latin-derived words in Italian. Before then, the pronunciation of Latin in church was the same as the pronunciation as Latin in other fields, and **tended to reflect the sound values associated with the nationality of the speaker** (Brittain, *Latin in Church; the history of its pronunciation*).

It seems like individual tags for geographic variations would rapidly get out of hand. Perhaps a catch-all such as [geographic-variation](https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/geographic-variation) would be appropriate?

Comment: Another one that is more connected to context than age might be `vulgar-latin`.

Comment: Cool, you half-answered [my question](http://latin.stackexchange.com/q/55/52), a basic example of this kind of questions. For now I have [tag:dialects] there, but [tag:geographic-variation] might be even better. I'll wait for the community to agree and I'll retag it.

Comment: Should there, perhaps, be some general tags `geolect`, `sociolect`, `ethnolect`, or would that be too linguistically oriented and/or too general altogether.

Comment: @CannedMan This question is so old, you're probably better off asking this in a new Meta question and linking back to this one.